# Mapview not working on real Android device via Expo React Native APK file

Tags: react-native

My Simple Mapview app not working on real device via Expo  React Native.
When I tested via ExpoGO on real device Android, it works.
But when I generated standalone APK file via EAS portal, and executed on Android device, then it started and immediately it disappeared, ( But I can still see it in background running )
When I tested simple HelloWorld app, this works, so issue is this Mapview component.

Also I tried to inject this line `provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}`, as recommended on many forums, even for Android is not necessary accoding docu... but not helped.
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/

I build this app with this cmd:
`eas build -p android --profile preview`

here is code:`

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from 'react-native-maps';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        style={styles.map}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: 37.78825,
          longitude: -122.4324,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
});
```

app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "SimpleMap",
    "slug": "SimpleMap",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.expo_andrej.SimpleMap"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "8360acb8-6326-4690-bb67-18cd0ad6e9dc"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

eas.json

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 7.1.2"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
      
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
``
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, issue fixed by adding API KEY

app.json

```
      "package": "com.expo_andrej.SimpleMap",
      "config": {
        "googleMaps": {
          "apiKey": "API-KEY"
        }
```